# Kafka Streams: configuring `AdminClientConfig` or `ConsumerConfig` without overriding the values both

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Working with kafka version: 2.0.1 & kafka-streams-scala version 2.0.1

Log DEBUG messages such as:

> DEBUG 2019-05-08 09:57:53,322 [he.kafka.clients.NetworkClient] [
>   ] [               ]: [Consumer
>   clientId=XXX-bd6b071d-a44f-4253-a3a5-539d60a72dd3-StreamThread-1-consumer,
>   groupId=XXX] Disconnecting from node YYY due to request
>   timeout."

led me to increase the request.timeout.ms value:

```
  private val config: Properties = new Properties
  config.put(StreamsConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "240000")
...
  private val streams: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config)
```

However, this sets the new value to 240000ms for both the `AdminClientConfig` and the `ConsumerConfig` (The default request.timeout.ms values for `AdminClientConfig` and the `ConsumerConfig` are actually different -- 120000ms and 40000ms respectively).

Is there any way to set the Kafka Streams configuration values for either the  `AdminClientConfig` or the `ConsumerConfig` *without* overriding the values of both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prefix any config with `consumer.` or `admin.` to apply it to only one client.

There is also `main.consumer.`, `restore.consumer.` and `global.consumer.` to distinguish the different consumers further. Using `consumer.` as prefix, the config is applied to all consumers.

Finally, there is also `producer.` prefix (just mention it for completeness).

Compare the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#naming